# Handling AJAX error (Native JS)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to handle AJAX error using below code but it is not working

```
function ajaxPost(url, data, success, error) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            if (typeof success === "function") {
                success(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }else if([404, 500 , 503, 504 ].indexOf(xmlhttp.status) > -1){
            if(typeof error === "function"){
                error();    
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Am I missing any other status code in `[404, 500 , 503, 504 ]`? I am not reinventing the wheel, I have programmed the whole DOM using native JavaScript and don't want to include 80KB file just for AJAX. Please help me on this.

The above function is successfully posting the data to the server but failed to raise error when server is unavailable. Please help me to handle this.

Comment: `console.log(xmlhttp.status);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
          // try this code

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {

                        var resp=eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');


                        if( xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {

                            // success

                        } else if( xmlhttp.status >= 500 ) {

                            // internal server error

                        } else if ( xmlhttp.status >= 402 && xmlhttp.status <= 420 ) {

                           // error

                        } else if( xmlhttp.status == 400 || xmlhttp.status == 401 ) {

                           // bad request & unauthorized error

                        }

                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always check for anything that isn't success, for example :

```
function ajaxPost(url, data, success, error) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            if (typeof success === "function") {
                success(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }else if(typeof error === "function" && (xmlhttp.status > 299 || xmlhttp.status < 200)){
            error();    
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```